# Equivalent to newline in c#

Tags: c#, windows

What would I place after my variable to make the `Console.WriteLine ("You input Y")`
appear on a different line? Here's the code:

```
static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my bool program!");
        Console.WriteLine("Input a NON capital y or n please.");

        char Y = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        if (Y == 'y')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You input Y");
        }
        else
        {
            if (Y == 'n')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You input N");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit the program, Have a good day!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can put the 2nd if right after the else instead of enclosing it in the else block.

Comment: @randomperson8800: C++ has the same feature.

Comment: in C++ you can still use `if(){}else if(){} else{}`

Comment: I'm used to putting if in else's from c++

Comment: I tried that in vs but it compiled an error code

Comment: Console.WriteLine("\nYou input Y");

Comment: possibly a case statement would be cleaner :)

Comment: @randomperson8800: `switch-case` statement

Comment: I think you need to prefer a book..

Comment: the `google` will solve many of your problems

Comment: So, You have to read it first before asking here.

Comment: No i found it but I'm looking for page i read it like a regular book and as a reference but switch case  didn't occur to me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
Environment.NewLine
```

which is a string that acts... as a newline.

Alternatively you can just use

```
Console.WriteLine()
```

with no parameters, if a single newline is all you want.

Answer (score 4):

```
Console.WriteLine();
```

with no parameters at all.

Answer (score 1):

`Console.WriteLine("\r\nYou input Y");`

the problem is since you are reading a key character it will perform output right after the input.

console.writeline() will work as well

In line with the comments on the question, you can do this in both C# and C++

```
if(something)
{
    doThis();
}
else if(somethingElse)
{
    doSomethingElse();
}
else
{
    kickChuckNorrisInTheTeeth();
}
```

if/else if/else is all supported in C# and C++